# Capturing video with sound, from cameras in Unity?

Tags: unity, camera, video

I want to capture video from cameras and save them in Unity. There is a function `Application.CaptureScreenShot()` but it only captures images. There is another function that only captures images, too.

It's said to be possible to capture images and attach them together to make a video file but I think it uses a lot of resources and makes the process heavy and in the end there is still no sound.

I mean ingame cameras not reall cameras. I want to capture videos from game

Is there any other way for me to record sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer for least spend of time is "video capture" plugin that is in asset store for free. but to use it and removing al bugs you have to get "SteamVR" plugin in asset store because "video capture" uses some "SteamVR" feature.

Answer (score 2):

Use what's built into Unity - the [video capture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-videocapture.html) API. Note that it says,

> You must enable the WebCam and Microphone capabilities to use the
>   VideoCapture API.

Otherwise google "unity video capture library" - there are some results on the Unity Store.

Comment: realy my bad. i think didn't explain completely. i mean cameras in the game not reall cameras and webcams. sorry

Comment: can you remove your answer to let other people know this question still need answer? thank you

Answer (score -4):

You could simply create a proper build and do a normal screen recording of the game. Why does it have to be recorded inside Unity?

Comment: sorry but you answer could be a comment. you cant want from a user to open a screen capture app to record your favorite video. believe me

Comment: Ah then I didn't get your question right. You want that the end user can record videos. Wasn't clear for me. For mobile I know Everyplay which is capable of this.

Comment: unfortunately I need it for pc. and there is no free plugin for it. can you remove you answer to let people know this question still needs answer. thank you.

Comment: The people know because you didn't accept an answer yet, no worries.